# Rolling Mean ValueError

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the rolling mean on a double-axis graph. However, I get the `ValueError: view limit minimum -36867.6 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units` error. My columns do have datetime objects in them so I am not sure why this is happening.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

lns1 = ax1.plot(df5['TIME'],
       df5["y"])

lns2 = ax2.plot(df3_plot.rolling(window=3).mean(),
                color='black')
```

df5 looks like this:

```
    TIME          y
0   1990-01-01  3.380127
1   1990-02-01  3.313274
2   1990-03-01  4.036463
3   1990-04-01  3.813060
4   1990-05-01  3.847867
...
355 2019-08-01  8.590325
356 2019-09-01  7.642616
357 2019-10-01  8.362921
358 2019-11-01  7.696176
359 2019-12-01  8.206370
```

And df3_plot looks like this:

```
    date           y
0   1994-01-01  239.274414
1   1994-02-01  226.126581
2   1994-03-01  211.591748
3   1994-04-01  214.708679
4   1995-01-01  223.093071
...
99  2018-04-01  181.889699
100 2019-01-01  174.500096
101 2019-02-01  179.803310
102 2019-03-01  175.570419
103 2019-04-01  176.697451
```

Futhermore, the graph comes out fine if I don't try using rolling mean for `df3_plot`. This means that the x-axis **is** a datetime for both. When I have

```py
lns2 = ax2.plot(df3_plot['date'],
                df3_plot['y'],
    color='black')
```

I get this graph[image: correct graph with datetimes as x-axis]

***Edit***

Suppose that df5 has another column 'y2' that is correctly rolling meaned with 'y'. How can I graph and label it properly? I currently have

```
df6 = df5.rolling(window=12).mean()
lns1 = ax1.plot(
     df6,
    label = 'y',         # how do I add 'y2' label correctly?
    linewidth = 2.0)
```

df6 looks like this:

```
    TIME    y      y2
0   1990-01-01  NaN     NaN
1   1990-02-01  NaN     NaN
2   1990-03-01  NaN     NaN
3   1990-04-01  NaN     NaN
4   1990-05-01  NaN     NaN
...     ...     ...     ...
355     2019-08-01  10.012447   8.331901
356     2019-09-01  9.909044    8.263813
357     2019-10-01  9.810155    8.185539
358     2019-11-01  9.711690    8.085016
359     2019-12-01  9.619968    8.035330
```

Comment: Have you checked if the 'Time' column in both dataframes is datetime Dtype ?

Comment: @dm2 When I run `df3_plot.date` I get `dtype: datetime64[ns]`. `df5.Time` also returns `dtype: datetime64[ns]`

Comment: Are you, as your code suggests, applying a rolling() method to the whole df3_plot DataFrame or just ['y'] column ?

Comment: @dm2 I think I am applying rolling to the whole dataframe. However, I'm not exactly sure what I am doing. I am trying to just smooth the line out a bit more. Which should I be applying the rolling() method to?

Comment: I tried doing `lns2 = ax2.plot(df3_plot.rolling(window=3, on='date').mean()` and `lns2 = ax2.plot(df3_plot.rolling(window=3, on='y').mean()`. Both are still giving me a ValueError

Comment: I'm only asking because if I try to do something similar to `df3_plot.rolling(window=3).mean()` (i.e. applying rolling() to the whole DataFrame) I'm getting a different error (`ops for Rolling for this dtype datetime64[ns] are not implemented`). So, if the code in lns2 assignment you have provided is correct, I don't think I could help you, however if it's only being applied to ['y'] column I have an idea what could be wrong.

Comment: @dm2 Does this mean anything to you? When I run `df3_plot.rolling(window=3).mean().plot()`, I get the correct graph shape. However, it is using the indices of 0 through 103 as the x-axis instead of my date column.

Comment: Well the dates are not in your index, but that still doesn't make sense because rolling() method doesn't work with datetime Dtype and you should get an error.

Comment: @dm2 Would it make sense if I set 'date' as the index? That way, rolling will still get the means for y, but plot using the index (now a datetime object).

Comment: It should work, and that's one of the option I would have suggested IF rolling() was applied to ['y'] column, but since as I've said the issue doesn't make sense, I don't know.

Comment: @dm2 Ohhhhh I understand your earlier questions know. Yes, I am just trying to roll the ['y'] column and then graph it over time.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but my question was if your code provided in the question is exactly as what you're doing, as this line `lns2 = ax2.plot(df3_plot.rolling(window=3).mean(), color='black')` should display a different error than in your question. If instead the line is `lns2 = ax2.plot(df3_plot['y'].rolling(window=3).mean(), color='black')`, the error you mention would make sense.

Comment: @dm2 I don't know why our error messages are different. However, doing `df3_plot.set_index('date', inplace=True)` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already caught this, but the problem is that `rolling` by default works on the index.  There is also an `on` parameter for setting a column to work on instead:

```
rolling = df3_plot.rolling(window=3, on='date').mean()
lns2 = ax2.plot(rolling['date'], rolling['y'], color='black')
```

Note that if you just do `df3_plot.rolling(window=3).mean()`, you get this:

```
            y
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.376586
3    0.168073
4    0.258431
..        ...
299  0.285585
300  0.327987
301  0.518088
302  0.300169
303  0.299366

[304 rows x 1 columns]
```

Seems like `matplotlib` tries to plot `y` here since there is only one column.  But the index is `int`, not dates, so I believe that leads to the error you saw when trying to plot over the other date axis.

When you use `on` to create `rolling` in my example, the result still has `date` and `y` columns, so you still need to reference the appropriate columns when plotting.

Comment: @Tom...I have a new question regarding how to label my lines correctly after doing rolling mean. I have added details in my question

Answer (score 1):

Making 'date' into the index of my dataframe did the trick: `df3_plot.set_index('date', inplace=True)`.

However, I'm not sure why the error messages are different for @dm2 and I.